# Can I set the item on the top right corner of the ActionBar in the ICS

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Can I set the item on the top right of the ActionBar? While Android mustn't allow me to do 
what I want to do like the title.**However,in my project,the need of it ask me to must do it like that**.
Following is my details:

> > actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS),
> >     "and manifest.xml " android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
> >     [image: This pic is like what I must design]

[image: this png is what we discussed about the title issue]

top PNG is what we discussed about the title issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be Android IOS's features. When screen is narrow the actionbar will take the bottom of the screen if you set `android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"` in manifest file.